# Browser Geolocation API not throwing error or respecting timeout

Tags: javascript, html, ios, macos, geolocation

This has felt like black magic to me for some time, and I'm hoping one of you can help clear this up. I have a geolocation function in JS that goes as follows:

```
// User Position
export function getPosition(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function success(pos) {
      var crd = pos.coords;
      console.log('we have succeeded with ' + crd)
      resolve(pos);
    }

    function failure(err) {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      reject();
    }

    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5500,
      maximumAge: 6000
    };

    // debugger;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure, options);
  });
};
```

and it is called within an async function with:

```
let position = await getPosition();
```

I have identified two cases where the promise is never resolved, somewhat predictably even with a timeout set.

- Browser is updated in iOS or MacOS and the new privacy settings revoke location access.
- Opened from a link in safari or chrome on iOS device

The `getPosition()` function will hang indefinitely, or far exceeding the timeout duration before the user is prompted.

Am I missing something in my code, or is this specific to new privacy settings with Apple operating systems where the geolocation API is falling on it's face?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/TravelManagerPolyfill.js) you'll see my matching observations: -

```
    const TIMEOUT_IS_USELESS
                       = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

and

```
            trackerId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(filterLocation, locError, {
                    enableHighAccuracy: accurate,
                    maximumAge: maxLocAge,
                    timeout: TIMEOUT_IS_USELESS
                });
```

Comment: So abandon all hope of timeout and find another way around it eh?

Comment: I went with sanity checks etc (see code) I have a MAX_SILENCE MAX_LOITER etc